# How to set value of select box in Set or ArrayList in spring mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, drop-down-menu

I have a class User{ Set.....} Car{String id,......}.
a select box in html page. I want that when user submit form, value of select box should be set in Set. How can i do it in Spring mvc.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Spring's `form` tag library, it allows you to bind the form directly to a Java object on the model.  The form values will reflect the corresponding values of the model object.

For example, if you have a select box for `user.title`, and the possible values come from another model object collection named `titles` and containing "President", "CEO", and "Developer", you can use the following:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="user">
...
<form:select path="title" items="${titles}" />
...
```

...then the HTML select will automatically reflect the value to which user.title has been set.